# PowerPoint VBA: How to save a pic in a particular file format & not the whole presentation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using vba in PowerPoint.  I'm trying to compress orginal picture files from a specified folder to a smaller size.  I was able to achieve that.  However, I want to save the new compressed picture into a destination folder.

The following code will save the presenation or slide with the picture.  But I only want the picture.  I'm pretty sure I have to use `ActivePresentation.SaveAs`.  But it will only let me save the slide.  How can I save the pic alone & not the slide?

Also, I seem to have another problem when I try to save the modified pic.  It saves the presentation into a folder in the destination with a filename of "Slide1.bmp".  Any idea why & how can I change this?

```
Dim strSrcPath As String, strDestPath As String
Dim strSrcPic As String
Dim objPic As Shape
Dim x as Integer

strSrcPath = "C:\Temp\Pics\In\"
strDestPath = "C:\Temp\Pics\Out\"

strSrcPic = Dir(strSrcPath)    

Do While strSrcPic <> ""
    x = x + 1
    Set objPic = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strSrcPath & strSrcPic, _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, _
        Height:=100)
    With objPic
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
    End With

    objPic.Select

    ActivePresentation.SaveAs _
        FileName:=strDestPath & "ModPicture(" & x & ").bmp", _
        FileFormat:=ppSaveAsBMP, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=msoFalse
    objPic.Delete
    strSrcPic = Dir    'Get next entry.
Loop
```

Comment: Powerpoint VBA is the wrong tool for the job. There are large numbers of free bulk image resizers available online.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JSRWilson for the following response:

"You do have to right click in View >Object Browser >> Show Hidden Members
Assuming objPic is still a reference to the compressed pic

`objPic.Export(strDestPath & "& "ModPicture(" & x & ").bmp", ppSaveAsBMP)`"